# What are the advantages and disadvantages of 24/7 Bitcoin trading?

Tags: security, trading

What are the advantages and disadvantages of 24/7 Bitcoin trading over traditional stock market which operates only 6 - 8 hours a day and 5 days a week? Any threats?

Answer (score 2):

The 24/7/365 bitcoin trading market is pretty unique in financial markets. Here are the advantages and disadvantages as I see them.

Advantages:
- more convenient: bitcoin can be bought and sold at any time and on any day.
- truly international: bitcoin can be traded during business hours in every country and every timezone.
- increased profitability: more trades means a good trader can make more money.

Disadvantages:
- increased risk: important market movements can occur while you're sleeping, causing trading losses.

Answer (score -2):

I would say that with out the regulated trading times such as a stock market you have a chance to lose everything while your sleeping, also with no set times you can't regulate a real price and the sell price becomes what ever who ever your selling them to wants to pay. The up side is no matter where in the world you are you can buy and sell them just as easily.

Comment: You "risk losing everything" only if you're careless. Just post some orders at a low price, and you're done.

Comment: That's not true unless you can actually place a stop order which aren't widely supported.

Answer (score -2):

I see only advantages now.
Here can be risks but here is the rebuttal for them:
http://cryptodetail.com/page/the-advantages-and-risks-of-cryptocurrency

Comment: Exchanges have hard time to make upgrades/maintenance as they are always live... Nasdaq have 12+ hours a day to do that.

Comment: While the linked page may contain great info, it's generally better to capture the main salient points in your answer in case the page "goes away".